# Blazor wasm debuging in VS2022 stopped working

Tags: blazor-webassembly

I'm developing blazor wasm app and debuging stopped working correctly in VS2022 17.1.6.

- I'm able to set breakpoints, but I can't view the values of any variables
- I can't step over lines (Frame not in module)
- If I create new blazor wasm project, debuging works correctly.

What Am I missing ?

I can see strange errors:

```
    dotnet.6.0.4.i2krt2oq01.js:1 /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/metadata/class.c:2227 <disabled>
    dotnet.6.0.4.i2krt2oq01.js:1 * Assertion: should not be reached at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/metadata/class.c:2228
    Assertion: should not be reached at /__w/1/s/src/mono/mono/metadata/class.c:2228
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have interloop between base and inherited component. In my case, I was calling base method which builds itself (layout via RenderFragment builder)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I could not see the value of variables, and breakpoints were not working.

My issue was resolved by changing the solution configuration from 'Release' to 'Debug'. See the below picture. My breakpoints have worked correctly, and I have been able to view the values of variables since making this change.

[image: Solution Configuration]